# Inserting large amounts of data into hive (around 64MB)

Tags: hadoop, hive, odbc

Ok, so I have a hive table on a remote hadoop node set up on a linux machine. I'm having an issue when attempting to insert a large json string, large as in possibly 64MB or more given that map reduce won't work well unless I approach that limit. I've successfully transfered over 8 - 9MB, but that's as high as it gets, if I attempt to do more than the query fails. I also had to override C#'s default json serializer to do this, not a good practice I know, but I really don't know any other way to do this.

Anyway this is how I store data into Hive:

```
namespace HadoopWebService.Controllers
{
    public class LogsController : Controller
    {
        // POST: HadoopRequest
        [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult Create(string json)
        {
            OdbcConnection hiveConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Hadoop Server;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX");
            hiveConnection.Open();
            Stream req = Request.InputStream;
            req.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string request = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
            ContentResult response;
            string query;

            try
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO TABLE error_log (json_error_log) VALUES('" + request + "')";
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, hiveConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.CommandText = query;
                response = new ContentResult { Content = "{status: 1}", ContentType = "application/json" };
                hiveConnection.Close();
                return response;
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                response = new ContentResult { Content = "{status: 0, message:" + error.ToString()+ "}" };
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.Message.ToString());
                hiveConnection.Close();
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some setting which I can use to insert larger amounts of data? I assume there must be some buffer that is failing to load everything. I've checked on google but I haven't found anything, mainly because this probably isn't the way to insert properly into Hadoop, but I'm really out of options right now, I can't use HDInsight, all I've got is the ODBC connection.

**EDIT:** This is the error I get:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000][HiveODBC]
>   (35) Error from Hive: error code: ‘0’ error message: ‘ExecuteStatement
>   finished with operation state: ERROR_STATE’.
>
> message:System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000]
>   [Microsoft][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '0' error
>   message: 'ExecuteStatement finished with operation state:
>   ERROR_STATE'.    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
>   SQL_API odbcApiMethod)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: 64M is not that big size for Hive actually. How does it fail ? What the stacktrace says ?

Comment: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: ‘0’ error message: ‘ExecuteStatement finished with operation state: ERROR_STATE’. That's what it says, I'm not quite sure what it means, all I know is that it starts showing up whenever I try to create a log file with more than 10000 messages

Comment: What do the server logs for Hive say? Additionally, have you tried enabling tracing in the driver itself and providing the information at the end of the log to see if anything might show up there?

Comment: Sorry to say, I have no clue on how to do any of that. And it seems that it won't be necessary anymore. My professor already checked this assignment, since it was our first time using Hadoop, he didn't mind that we had 9 MB files, although I do know that having files that size is problematic. It will hamper MapReduce if I have a lot of small files, since I already had that problem before.